# ASP.NET Hidden field's OnValueChange

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have several different scenarios, all with different longitudes and latitudes (and other data, but that's beside the point) in JSON. I am parsing the JSON ok, and have been able to get the desired values. What I would like to do is transfer these values to the CodeBehind.
What I am doing so far is something like this:

This is the responsible script:

```
function getScenarioDetails(json) {      
    $("#Welcome").text("Welcome user " + json.user);   
    $("#longitude").val(json.current_loc.lon).change();       
    $("#latitude").val(json.current_loc.lat).change();     
}
```

And these are the hidden fields:

```
<form runat="server">
   <asp:HiddenField runat="server" id="longitude" OnValueChanged="valueChanged"   />
   <asp:HiddenField runat="server" id="latitude" OnValueChanged="valueChanged"  />  
</form>
```

I realise that the value is being changed. But something is going wrong with the OnValueChanged as it is not firing. What exactly am I doing wrong?

Comment: i don't think when the hidden field is rendered as hidden input its id is exactly `latititude` or `longitude`, Unless you have set the static id mode

Comment: as @PSL mentioned the ID of your hidden fields are likely to be different on the client side since .Net prefixes the client side ids

Comment: set `ClientIDMode="Static"` property on your HiddenField http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I have tried ClientIDMode="Static", nothing different happens (I've added a breakpoint on the valueChanged method but it never enters the method in the first place)

Answer (score 4):

I will try to explain this, First the client id is generated based on the NamingContainer parents so if your hidden fields are nested in a container you should use the property ClientIDMode and set the value to Static to ensure the client id is the same in your script.

The ValueChange event is fired when a control cause a postback so if you put a button that has the onclick event it cause a postack and the ASP.Net lifecycle starts executing the ValueChange event for your hidden inputs, Some controls as DropDownList has a property AutoPostBack when it set to true it makes a postback as soon the javascript change event happens, so it not wait until a postback occurs. The HiddeField doesn't have a AutoPostBack property so if you really need to postack after you change the values you could make a postback so:

```
function getScenarioDetails(json) {      
    $("#Welcome").text("Welcome user " + json.user);   
    $("#longitude").val(json.current_loc.lon);       
    __doPostBack('longitude', ''); 
    .....
}
```